# Facebook user doesn't have permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-authentication

A user who has already authorized the app, but denied "Post Automatic."  How can I help them re-add permissions?  I even removed the app from their list and deleted their user.  When they resign in it doesn't re-ask for them to permission?

```
NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"FACEBOOK_INVITE_MESSAGE", nil);
NSString *link = ITUNES_URL;
NSString *description = NSLocalizedString(@"FACEBOOK_INVITE_DESCRIPTION", nil);
NSString *picture = @"http://trivi.al/Content/images/icon72.png";
NSMutableDictionary *tParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                message,     @"message",
                                link,        @"link",
                                description, @"description",
                                picture,     @"picture", nil];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:[[sender superview] superview].tag];

NSDictionary *playerDict = [((NSArray*)[self.sortedUsersWithoutApp valueForKey:((NSString*)[self.sortedKeysForUsersWithoutApp objectAtIndex:indexPath.section])]) objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[PFFacebookUtils facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", [playerDict objectForKey:@"id"]] 
                      andParams:tParams
                    andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: can you post all the code you are using for logging user in and get perms?

Comment: Yeah this should be pretty straightforward, just send them to the auth dialog again

Comment: Yeah tried that, it doesn't even have it in his list of requested permissions.  Just he and a few others have this problem.